# Unable to save text changes made by Javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe

Working with: text on a web page

Using tools: javascripts like the ones found 
here: http://www.tweakandtrick.com/2011/03/javascript-tricks-edit-websites-in.html
and here: http://createjs.org/

Current problem: When a text is edited, there is no way to save those changes in order to comeback to it after refresh or reopening the page, and all changes are lost.

QUESTION: Is it possible to somehow save changes made to the text of the page, and not loose them after a page refresh/reset?

Limitations: no access to the webpage being edited.

The GOAL: Open a random page, make changes to the text using javascript above, saving all steps in such way, that I could apply them later from same or another PC by opening the same page and running the script.

Answer (score 1):

This is fundamental to javaScript, all changes that it makes are only temporary, lasting only whilst the page is loaded in the browser. JavaScript has no access to the computer file system of the server where it is stored nor your file system from the browser and as such, can not modify or write to its self or to your computer, other than in [cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp).

As mentioned, you can use and store cookies in user browser that will remember the state of any thing written for so long as the cookie is not deleted from the browsers cache.

You can do as you have specifically requested, by taking your JavaScript with you and using a browser plug-in such as [greasemonkey](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Greasemonkey) (on firefox) to run your code, when selected from the drop down menu, else when triggered by a web page and the browser.